# Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the Ubuntu environment，Refer to the "ROS NDK How to cross-compile any other ROS package for Android" tutorial, compile sick_tim,./do_docker to sick_tim when I run the wrong  as follows:

```
  ==> add_subdirectory(sick_tim)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:106 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  sick_tim/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251919/could-not-find-pkgconfig-(missing:-pkg_config_executable)/) by [zzkzsmj](https://answers.ros.org/users/28999/zzkzsmj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-14**:
Without more context (OS, how you installed things, what you are trying to do, which version of ROS, etc), the best I can do is that it would seem you don't have PkgConfig installed. Try installing it and see whether that helps.

**Comment by [zzkzsmj](https://answers.ros.org/users/28999/zzkzsmj/) on 2017-01-17**:
Hello, I was in the Ubuntu environment, the use of ROS NDK compiler errors,

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Please update your original question (use the *edit* button/link) and give us enough information to help you. What exactly are you trying to do, and what set of steps led to the error message that you copy/pasted.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
I have no direct experience with the NDK integration, but from the error message I would say that the docker image that is being used does not have PkgConfig installed or CMake can't find it. I recommend you open an issue [here](https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android.git).

**Comment by [zzkzsmj](https://answers.ros.org/users/28999/zzkzsmj/) on 2017-01-17**:
Well, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently we don't support using PkgConfig with the ROS NDK, you will need to use a workaround to specify the correct variables for the library you need to use (in this case libusb). [Here's](https://github.com/ekumenlabs/roscpp_android/blob/master/patches/robot_pose_ekf.patch#L11) an example on how we do that for another package.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1